# What are the main issues that are preventing a human mission to Mars?

Tags: biophysics, rocket-science, space-mission

Is it just because it'd be very expensive?

Or are there serious problems that need to be dealt with, studied and solved? If so, what are they?

Comment: "much of the hardware that can get humans to Mars already exists and is ready to fly". So yes, money. And planning takes a long time.

Comment: Why would you post this to Physics SE?!? Consider the [space.se] beta... Just flag if you want me to migrate it.

Comment: This most certainly is better fodder for the Space Exploration SE site. I supplied an answer, but except for precision landing, my answer has little to do with physics, and even precision landing is more of an engineering problem rather than a physics problem.

Comment: @dmckee Don't migrate it. This is a dup in SX. http://space.stackexchange.com/q/4/

Comment: @dmckee and all others who don't consider this to be a physics question: How do you slow down a huge payload for landing on a planet without atmosphere? Do you want to take your own "mass" along to be accelerated far beyond escape velocity to slow you down by Newton's third law? Or do you prefer a different design where a huge mass stays in orbit, like used for the moon missions? Both options seem challenging...

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4535/ 'nough said. The problem---well outlined by David H below---are all in the realm of engineering, physiology, finance and group psychology. Yes, if you dig deep enough you can find a physics problem to hold up, but that is true of endless other question that have no place here.

Comment: @dmckee - I am not David H. That is a different user. (No detraction to David H; he gives nice answers.) To quote Dr. Seuss, *There once was a woman named Mrs. McCave who had twenty-three sons and named them all Dave.* There are just too many of us Davids around. I once worked in an office of five where four of us were named David.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Money certainly is one issue, but it is far from the only issue. It isn't even the biggest issue.

**Issue #1: Humans need air, water, and food.**

We can live without air for a few seconds, without water for a few hours, without food for a few days. And then we die. We need air, water, and food. And we don't know how to do that on Mars.

There are conjectures that various chemical processes can be used to liberate oxygen from the Martian regolith or Martian atmosphere. These are but conjectures. Taking a conjecture (technology readiness level 1) to something that can reliably be used to support human life (technology readiness level 9) is not an easy process. Generating oxygen is quite feasible, but reliability is a different matter.

Water is even tougher nut to crack than is air. Food? What we do know is that every attempt to make a self-sustaining environment has failed miserably.

Basically, we don't know how to do that.

**Issue #2: Humans need to come home.**

Given the above, sending humans to Mars permanently would be murder. We haven't the foggiest idea how to send humans on a permanent basis. Until we solve the problems of air, water, and food, we need to bring our explorers home. This represents an exponential increase in cost.

This means sending a launch-capable lander to the surface. The biggest thing we've sent to the surface of Mars is the 900 kilogram Curiosity rover. A launch-capable lander would necessarily be many orders of magnitude larger. Crossing multiple orders of magnitude in physics is easy. In engineering, it's not so easy.

Basically, we don't know how to do that.

**Issue #3: Precision landing.**

The *Mars One* concept shows multiple vehicles, side by side, on the surface of Mars. That is pure science fiction.

Because of issue #1, we'll need to send lots of supplies to the Martian explorers, enough to last the hundreds of days that orbital mechanics says they will have to stay on Mars before coming home. The amount needed is staggering, much more than can be carried on a single lander. That means multiple vehicles landing on Mars, all carrying supplies needed by explorers. They'll need to land close enough to one another that our intrepid Mars explorers could conceivably make a foray to and retrieve those resources.

There's one minor problem here: This is yet another "we don't know how to do that" kind of problem. The current concept of "precision landing" on Mars means not missing the target by hundreds of kilometers.

Basically, we don't know how to do that.

**Issue #4: Humans can be stupid and crazy.**

This is perhaps the hardest nut to crack. The premise behind *Mars One* is that it will be a highly-watched reality TV show. The kinds of people that make a reality TV show garner big ratings are exactly the kinds of people we absolutely do not want to send to Mars. Various navies of the world have studied the personality traits of people who do well on long, isolated assignments in submarines. Needless to say, these are not the drama kings and drama queens that make reality TV so entertaining.

The shortest round trip to Mars will be over two years long. That's too much time for even the most stable of personalities.

**Addendum**

I recently left working for NASA after over a three decade long career there. (I hope I still have another decade to go, but elsewhere.) I worked with people who studied the Mars problem. The next good opportunity to send people to Mars is only a few years away. That's too short. The opportunity after that occurs in 2035. The twenty years between now and then might well provide enough time to change "we don't know how to do that" into "we absolutely can do that".

Comment: Nice. Alas, exactly zero of these points are physics.

Comment: @dmckee - Exactly. Or almost. Two of them, air/water/food and precision landing (which would be the one thing I do know about (did know about)), do involve physics.

Comment: Even that is basically an engineering problem. If you could bring the craft you *really* wanted you could put down where you really wanted. (Imaging just killing most of your orbital velocity and then coming down on a Heinleinesque pillar of fire ... wasteful, but straight forward.) The trade-off comes from the mass limit on getting the fool thing there in the first place, which makes it a *hard* engineering problem or you and your colleagues would have licked it years ago.

Comment: @dmckee - I'm not arguing with you. This is an engineering problem. In the spherical cow world of physics, all of the details of where you are / when you are / how fast you're going just vanish. It is these spherical cow assumptions that vanish when engineering comes into play.

Comment: regarding no 2: there are a lot of volunteers that would be fine with a mission to not come back, just for being the first there. Which will probably make point 1 moot too

Comment: Precision landing should not be as difficult as you suggest.  The Curiousity landing ellipse was 20x7 km, not "hundreds of kilometers", and this was without any particular aiming point.  Given a target - the first successful lander - with a radio beacon, it should easily be possible to make all landings within a km or so.  Also note that this has been done. Apollo 12 landed within walking distance of a previous Surveyor lander: http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/LRO/multimedia/lroimages/lroc_20090903_apollo12.html

Comment: @PlasmaHH - That's fine until they start dying. Then watch. Or rather, don't watch. The Mars One reality TV show will not show people dying.

Comment: @jamesqf - That 20x7 km ellipse was the one sigma value. Multiply by three to get a realistic three sigma uncertainty. Then add in the fact that there are no roads on Mars. A 20x7 km one sigma ellipse is orders of magnitudes too large for human concerns.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - The kind of people who would be willing to die to be the first to Mars are exactly the kind of people who should not go to Mars (with the exception of a sexy reality TV show). Mixing metaphors, these are the people who will make NASA's diaper incident look like small potatoes.

Answer (score 3):

There is another problem here. How to shield humans from the hard radiation (high energy protons and neutrons) from the Sun and Galactic cosmic ray sources, once outside the Earth's magnetosphere.

Analysis of data from instruments on board the Mars Curiosity spacecraft and on the Rover itself, allowed [Zeitlin et al. (2014)](http://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/8thmars2014/pdf/1151.pdf) to compare the equivalent radiation dose (or dose-equivalent rate) and the NASA design reference mission (180 days out, 500 days on the surface and 180 days back) with current health and safety standards.

The outward/inward journey features an equivalent dose rate of 1.8 milli-sieverts/day and then a further 0.64 milli-sieverts/day whilst on the surface. A total dose of 1 sievert (=100 rem) would be experienced (about the same as 2000 medical X-ray investigations)- although it should be noted that the Sun wasn't particularly active during these measurements.

This does not appear to be a show-stopper and presumably some clever shielding options could reduce this a bit. An acute dose of this size would increase cancer risk, it's about 5 times the recommended amount of occupational exposure and about 50 times the average dose received in the USA.

However, it is not clear what would happen if there were bursts of strong solar activity whilst in the cruise phase or on the Martian surface. Some sort of contingency plan would be needed, but it is difficult to shield against the high energy Galactic cosmic rays which would be more prevalent in periods of *low* solar activity.